# Perform SELECT INTO Statement and add Primary Key afterwards

Tags: performance, sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I imrpove the performance of this T-SQL statement?

```
SELECT Code, Description 
INTO [DBApps_Pulse_WarehouseAreas].[dbo].[Tbl_Partmaster]
FROM SYSDataBridge.dbo.View_Pulse_Partmaster_Synchronized

ALTER TABLE [DBApps_Pulse_WarehouseAreas].[dbo].[Tbl_Partmaster] ADD PRIMARY KEY (Code)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code effectively writes the table twice.

Once as a heap and then again as a clustered index (with an intermediate sort step) after you add the primary key.

I'd just create the table upfront with the desired primary key and insert into it.

```
USE DBApps_Pulse_WarehouseAreas;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_Partmaster]
  (
     Code        VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Tbl_Partmaster PRIMARY KEY,
     Description NVARCHAR(500) NOT NULL
  );

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Tbl_Partmaster]  WITH (TABLOCKX)
SELECT Code,
       Description
FROM   SYSDataBridge.dbo.View_Pulse_Partmaster_Synchronized;
```

For at least three versions of SQL Server an insert into an empty B tree has been able to be minimally logged.

In order to avoid page splits there might be a sort operator in the execution plan if the estimated number of rows is sufficiently high (or if the source has an index that could potentially present the selected columns in order of code this direct insert might avoid the need to sort all together).

Finally avoid Hungarian notation such as `Tbl_`. At best it adds nothing but clutter. At worst at some point you might want to refactor the database and transparently replace the table with a view without updating calling code. Then the `Tbl_` prefix would be down right misleading.

Comment: I had to lookup what TABLOCKX means and found this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102152/tablock-vs-tablockx However they advise not to use TABLOCKX or TABLOCK unless you absolutely needed it for some edge case. Is this an edge case?

Comment: @Joel - This is to take advantage of minimal logging (not needed if you have trace flag 610). `TABLOCK ` would work equally well.